# Is there a Perl's mirror() function equivalent in python

Tags: python, perl

I'm just trying to download video files from the webserver which has authentication.
I used to download the script using perl using its mirror() function, now i'm trying to do the same in python.

But i'm not able to download the video files only text files are getting downloaded.
Any help in this regard will be great.

Thanks in advance

I browsed and tried with **urllib2.urlRetreive()** but still i'm not able to download.
This is the code I'm using, pls have a look and help me in this regard.

```
file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
print file_name
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
meta = u.info()
print meta.getheaders("Content-Length")
print "\nAfter content length"
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
    print "in While\n"
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    print buffer
    if not buffer:
       break

    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
    status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
    print status,
f.close()
```

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: Why are you trying to re-create `wget` in Python?

Comment: There's no such thing as Perl's `mirror` function. It's probably LWP::Simple's mirror function you're referring to.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - possibly to avoid shelling out in code? that's why I'd use `mirror()`. Of course, if you're having to implement it yourself, it's probably not an improvement when wget will likely be better tested, more robust etc